# How can I handle unstructured JSON fields in Avro schema, like google.protobuf.Struct in protobuf?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, avro, clickhouse

I'm making App -> Kafka -> ClickHouse pipeline, having problems with Avro format.
Is there a valid way to have dynamic field in Avro, something like [google.protobuf.Struct](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#struct) in protobuf.

My schema is mostly typed but one dynamic `meta` field that can't be typed at all (actually it's unstructured JSON, fields are very volatile and as well as varying field depth).

Does it make sense to use Avro here or JSON (with compression) will be as good?

Example schema:

```json
{
  "schema": {
    "name": "SomeRecord",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      { "name": "datetime", "type": {"type": "long", "logicalType": "timestamp-millis" }},
      { "name": "field1", "type": "string" },
      { "name": "field2 "type": "long" },
      { "name": "meta", "type": "??? what to put here ???" }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can use string field and store JSON inside, but is there better solutions?